# Using .query() in t-sql to get only inner text

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

How can I use the `.query()` syntax of `t-sql` to select a specific node, but only get the inner text rather than the inner text wrapped in the node tags?

As in, when I do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [XMLContent].query('/Event/Username'), * from Events
```

I get:

```
<Username>BURGUNDY</Username>
```

But what I want is is just `BURGUNDY`. Obvious I could do some sub strings to get it, but I was hoping there was a quick and easy way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the xquery data() function:

```
[XMLContent].query('data(/Event/Username)')
```

But, this will return XML as the type (even though there are no tags).

You could also use .value instead of .query:

```
[XMLContent].value('/Event[1]/Username[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```

Comment: I have a query that returns many rows.  Each row is an xml document.  When I run [XMLContent].query() I only receive one value back when there should be a value for every row in my original select?  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 6):

```
declare @xml xml;
set @xml = '<Event><Username>BURGUNDY</Username></Event>'

Select @xml.value('/Event[1]/Username[1]', 'varchar(30)');
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me when I put a leading / in front of my xpath. E.G. Select @xml.value('Event[1]/Username[1]', 'varchar(30)'); works for me locally, but Select @xml.value('/Event[1]/Username[1]', 'varchar(30)'); does **not**.

Answer (score 3):

use .value() instead of .query()